# multiplatform makefile defines were -dlinux_64 for linux, what use for mac

Tags: makefile, multiplatform

My makefile has the following defines for linux.  What would the equivalent be for the mac build?  I'm not seeing anything in an internet search for linux and mac defines or -dlinux_64.

```
DEFINES=-D_INCLUDE_POSIX_SOURCE -DLINUX -DLINUX_64 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
DEBUG_DEFINES=$(DEFINES)
PROFILE_DEFINES=$(DEFINES)
```

During the build, it's showing like this:

```
/usr/bin/gcc -MM -fPIC -O2 -m64 -Wall -D_INCLUDE_POSIX_SOURCE -DLINUX -DLINUX_64 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -I../inc -I.  jdmainct.c > jdmainct.d
/usr/bin/gcc -fPIC -O2 -m64 -Wall -D_INCLUDE_POSIX_SOURCE -DLINUX -DLINUX_64 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -I../inc -I.  -c jdmarker.c -o jdmarker.o
...
```

Do I need to change that for the mac build?  What is the equivalent for mac? Thanks!

Comment: It depends on what the code you're compiling is looking for.  Those macros are not used by the compiler for anything.  You'd have to look in `jdmainct.c` etc. to see what those macros are used for and whether there are different ones needed for OS X builds.

Comment: I grepped for LINUX in the code dirs and don't see anything except in the makefile for that line.  Maybe it doesn't matter if I still use -DLINUX and -DLINUX_64.